# Error in python: variable won't be stored when using if/else

Tags: python

I'm making a program where I need to take user input and read through a file to obtain the full line information using the input. When compiling my program, I get this error:

```
  File "/Users/annahuynh/Desktop/huynh_phones.py", line 29, in <module>
    if line == last_name:
NameError: name 'last_name' is not defined
```

If any help is available, it would be appreciated!

The phones.txt file is a list of "first name, last name, and phone number". Input example would be: Andrew Garfield

```
    # opens phones.txt 
    f = open("phones.txt", 'r')

    #stores in variable text
    text = f.read()

    # prompts user for input
    print('Enter a last name, or first and last name: ')

    # stores input as variable x
    x = input().lower()

    # stores split x into variable split
    split = x.split()

    # stores length of number of words in split as numWords
    numWords = len(split)

    # returns error message if input is incorrect, otherwise stores split strings
    if len(x) == 0 or numWords > 2:
        print('Error. Please enter valid input of either a last name, or first and last name.')
    elif len(x) == 1:
            last_name = x.split()
    elif len(x) == 2:
            first_name, last_name = x.split(" ", 1)

    while True:
            line = f.readline().lower()
            if line == last_name:
                    break
                    print(line, end="")
            elif line == first_name:
                    break
                    print(line, end="")
```

Comment: What do you think the error means? And what is your expected output instead of this error?

Comment: What are you giving in as input ? There seems to be a mistake in logic and also you have not initialized any variable.  You code will surely go into `while` loop but its not sure if it will go inside `if condition.`. In this case your code is not getting inside the if condition. Please share the input you are providing.

Comment: I think it means that in the if statements, where i'm trying to store the split() input of the user for first name/last name, it is not storing into the variables of first_name / last_name and I can't seem to figure out why. ): The output should show the full line of the file using the user input to find the phone number of the person with their first/last name.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] for this error. Replace `input()` by an initialized variable so we don't have to guess what the values are.

Comment: Stick an `else` block after the `first_name, last_name = x.split(" ", 1)` line and print the value of `x`. That should make your problem apparent.

Comment: Look at `if len(x) == 0 or numWords > 2: ...`. There is nothing in your code that defines `last_name`, except when `len(x)` is 1 or 2. Consider the case where `len(x)` is **not** 1 or 2 (e.g. when it is 0 or 3 or 4, etc.), then `last_name` will not be defined.

Comment: I think it would be better if you explain what is your goal here more elaborately. As @PrashantKumar said, when any input does not fall into any of your IF ELSE condition then the error occurs. Please provide us the TXT file content, your possible inputs and desired outputs :)

Comment: Another thing to watch out for: when you open "phones.txt" you read the entire contents with f.read().  But then you try to continue reading lower down in the while loop - but f.readline() will return an empty string at that point because you've read everything already

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `last_name` outside the if-else ladder. You can initialize it with blank, and later re-initialize it as per the condition. This way, `last_name` will be initialized, and will also not satisfy the condition as it is blank/null. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The var `last_name` will only be initialized if the condition `elif len(x) == 1:` or `elif len(x) == 2:` is satisfied. If the above conditions are not executed then variables `last_name` and `first_name` will not get initialized and you will get error at `if line == last_name:` and `elif line == first_name:`.

So initialize the var `last_name = ""` and `first_name=""` before the if `if len(x) == 0 or numWords > 2:` condition.